# Discard the timezone information of date object

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I need to save all time data in my DB in UTC format,

And When I fetch them from DB into JS it will look like `2016-09-01T02:39:08.495Z`

However, when I tried to format them.

The JS and JS library will try to convert them into user local time.

However, this creepy conversion will break my app.

How could I simple show the format in `YYYY/mm/dd` or `YYYY/mm/dd HH:MM`

That is discard the timezone information. Don't let any lib try to convert the time into any timezone.

eg: `2016-09-01T02:39:08.495Z` -> `2016/09/01` , or `2016/09/01 02:39` for user from all the world should get the same format.

Sometimes, users in USA will see the `2016/08/31` and user in JAPAN will see `2016/09/01` for the same data.

`moment(time_value).format(DT_FORMAT);`

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: I don't get your question, do you wanna use momentJS library or plain JS ?